# Array of templated objects

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

Here is my task:

Realize template class which will represent cuboid, where length, width and height can be any data type.
Array of cuboids can also be argument of template function, so overload all needed operators.
(When compare cuboids, larger is one with larger volume)

Here is what I did:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class cuboid{
private:
    int length_of_array;
    T length, width, height;
    T * arr;
public:
    cuboid();
    cuboid(T *, int);
    cuboid(T, T, T);
    ~cuboid();
    cuboid(const cuboid &);
    T volume();
};

template <class T>
cuboid<T>::cuboid(){
}

template <class T>
cuboid<T>::cuboid (T *n, int len){
    length_of_array = len;
    arr = new cuboid <T> [length_of_array];
    for(int i = 0; i < length_of_array; i++){
    arr[i] = n[i];
    }
}

template <class T>
cuboid<T>::cuboid(T o, T s, T v){
    length = o;
    width = s;
    height = v;
}

template <class T>
cuboid<T>::~cuboid(){
    delete [] arr;
    arr = 0;
}

template <class T>
T cuboid<T>::volume(){
    return length * width * height;
}

template <class T>
cuboid<T>::cuboid(const cuboid & source){
    length_of_array = source.length_of_array;
    arr = new cuboid <T> [length_of_array];
    for(int i = 0; i < length_of_array; i++){
    arr[i] = source.arr[i];
    }
}

int main(){
    int a, b, c, length;
    cuboid <int> *n;
    cout << "How many cuboids array contains? " << endl;
    cin >> length;
    n = new cuboid <int> [length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    n[i] = cuboid <int> (a,b,c);
    }
    cuboid <int> arr(n, length);
}
```

I can't compile it (because of last line in main program). Any idea?

Comment: You should show the exact error message as well as the code

Comment: The last line would require a constructor taking `cuboid<int>*` and `int`. You don't have any such constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your compile error:

```
main.cpp:70:31: error: no matching function for call to 'cuboid<int>::cuboid(cuboid<int>*&, int&)'
     cuboid <int> arr(n, length);
                               ^
```

It tells you that you don't have the appropriate constructor. You're trying to call `cuboid<int>(cuboid<int>*, int)`, but all you have is `cuboid<int>(int*, int)`. Now, I could tell you how to fix this specifically, but instead I will fix your other problem: your design.

Your problem is:

> Realize template class which will represent cuboid, where length, width and height can be any data type.

And part of your solution to that makes perfect sense:

```
template <class T>
class cuboid {
private:
    T length, width, height;
};
```

But why does it *also* have a `T*` and a length? What is the array for? And why are you assigning that array to a `cuboid*` in your constructor? That code only compiles because you never instantiated that constructor. If you want a collection of `cuboid`s, the right way to do that is to use a container class. Something like:

```
std::vector<cuboid<int>> cuboids;
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    cuboids.push_back(cuboid(a, b, c));
}
```

Writing a class that is *both* a `cuboid` *and* a collection of them, even if you wrote it correctly, is a pretty clear violation of the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 0):

For `cuboid<int>` you have a constructor that accepts `int*, int` parameters, not `cuboid<int>*, int`. You should write a copy constructor:

```
cuboid(const cuboid<T>&);
```

or (in this case more straighforward) a constructor from another `cuboid` pointer:

```
cuboid(const cuboid<T>*)
```

or (not encouraged) provide a getter to access the inner array:

```
const T* get_arr() const;
```

(and change the `cuboid<T>::cuboid(T*, int)` constructor to take `const T*`).

Comment: Um, I think he needs a constructor from cuboid<T>* in this case, not a copy constructor.

Comment: @BlackCat Copy constructor would be most idiomatic in this case (still would work with a pointer after dereferencing). However, the second option I'm mentioning in my answer is just that what you said (expect it has `const`).