# C++ - Array og template class objects

Tags: c++, templates

Here is my task:

Implement template class cuboid, where dimensions (width, length and height) can be of any data type. Array of cuboidscan also be argument of template function, so it is neccessary to overload needed operators.
Write main program where array of cuboidswill be declared and initialized with dimensions of data type float.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class cuboid{
private:
    T length, width, height;
    cuboid *arr;
    int length_of_array;
public:
    cuboid();
    cuboid(cuboid*, int);
    cuboid(T, T, T);
    ~cuboid();
    T volume(cuboid);
    cuboid& operator = (const cuboid&);
};

template <class T>
cuboid<T>::cuboid(){
}

template <class T>
cuboid<T>::cuboid(cuboid *n, int len){
    length_of_array = len;
    arr = new cuboid <T> [length_of_array];
    for(int i = 0; i < length_of_array; i++){
    arr[i] = n[i];
    }
}

template <class T>
cuboid<T>::cuboid(T o, T s, T v){
    length = o;
    width = s;
    height = v;
}

template <class T>
    cuboid<T>::~cuboid(){
    delete [] arr;
    arr = 0;
}

template <class T>
T cuboid<T>::volume(cuboid b){
    if(length * width * height > b.length * b.width * b.height){
    return length * width * height;
    }
    else{
    return b.length * b.width * b.height;
    }
}

template <class T>
cuboid<T> & cuboid<T>::operator=(const cuboid& source){
    length = source.length;
    width = source.width;
    height = source.height;
    return *this;
}

int main(){
    int length;
    float a, b, c;
    cout << "How many cuboids array has? " << endl;
    cin >> length;
    cuboid<float> *arr;
    arr = new cuboid <float> [length];
    for(int i = 0;i < length; i++){
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    arr[i] = cuboid <float> (a,b,c);
    }
    cuboid <float> n(arr, length);
}
```

I compile it successfuly, but as soon as I start to enter dimensions of objects of array, program crashes. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I modified original code (and formulation of problem), it is cuboid instead of rectangle

Comment: Good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Hi chris, thanks for reply. I started relatively recently with programming in C++, I have a lot to learn. Can you please tell me exactly where I made mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does it crash?

Comment: @Buddy,  I run program, I enter length of array ("How many cuboids array has? ") and then as soon as I start to enter dimensions it crashes...

Comment: What compiler/IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks, gcc compiler

Comment: Same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32314277/2069064)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line of your code (along with the destructor):

```
arr[i] = rectangle <float> (a,b,c);
```

It allocates your new rectangle object **on the stack** using a constructor which does not allocate the `arr` array (which is stored on the heap according to your implemention).

Right after that the destructor is called:

```
template <class T>
rectangle<T>::~rectangle() {
std::cout << "D1" << std::endl;
    delete[] arr;
    arr = 0;
}
```

which tries to `delete[]` the `arr`, although in this case it hasn't been allocated.

One solution would be to fix you destructor so that it would take into account this case.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm not sure I know how to fix it. Can you please do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can just start by checking if `arr != nullptr` in you destructor (though you are also trying to store many rectangle objects inside a single rectangle object, I would rather use something like `std::vector`).